# Javascript comparison for Blank Object Literal

Tags: javascript

I am quite confused with the Javascript behaviour with some comparisons.

For this statement

```
let b = {}
b == 0 // returns false
```

Also this statement

```
0 == {} // returns false
```

But this statement

```
{} == 0 // throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

On the similar note if we check with Arrays, it works

```
[] == 0 // returns true without error
```

So I am a little bit confused. How Javascript engine is behaving in both scenarios. Any explanation would help a lot.

Comment: `==` does type conversion. I recommend reading up on this topic.

Comment: In {} == 0, javascript interprets your curly brace as a block instead of an object

Comment: Thanks, @evolutionxbox I will read on that.

Comment: @Faly, I get your point, seems like it.